# Typing an object of functions that dynamically calls functions with string keys and passes params to returned function

Tags: typescript

Suppose *for reasons* I need an object with functions as keys, so that I can dynamically call functions with strings. For example:

```js
const add_one = (n) => {
  return n + 1;
};

const add_two = (n) => {
  return n + 2;
};

const add_three = (n) => {
  return n + 3;
};

const functionHelper = {
  add_one,
  add_two,
  add_three,
};

var names = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  let funName = `add_${names[i]}`;
  let result = functionHelper[funName](1);
  console.log(`Adding ${names[i]}: ${result}`);
};
```

I am attempting to type `functionHelper` but am puzzled with how to go about it. Here is what I have so far:

```
const add_one = (n: number) => {
  return n + 1;
};

const add_two = (n: number) => {
  return n + 2;
};

const add_three = (n: number) => {
  return n + 3;
};

interface Helper {
  (): any;
};

const functionHelper: Helper = {
  add_one,
  add_two,
  add_three,
};

var names: string[] = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  let funName: string = `add_${names[i]}`;
  let result = functionHelper[funName](1);
  console.log(`Adding ${names[i]}: ${result}`);
};
```

The resulting error:

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'add_one' does not exist in type 'Helper'

Comment: Use type inference. `const functionHelper = {add_one, add_two, add_three}`. Now if you want to use this inferred strong type in another context, like annotating a parameter, just write `type Helper = typeof functionHelper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `Helper` interface as:

```
interface Helper {
    [key: string]: (n: number) => number;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgEwQfXAUxgXhgCjALhjAFcBbAIzQCcBKLAPhgG8AoGGKtKYqsImANQwAjAG4WAX3EtQkWIhRQA7iCy4CRMpVoNmbDlx58+QgEzipLGeGjwkyKAAtOGbHkIkK1Opkat2nNy8-EIAzBbSAJZgUNQAZnDAGAASaAA2AA7UeuzsANoA1mgAnoTQVNEA5gC6hO6aXjq+DdoRVrK2ccRgwFCR4KmZ1ISDWVRq-nYo6AA0+goOKnPsC04uc5YsAG5w42BwpGgQZVAVYJV51Wp5AOToNzMwN8ogD09raGg31dJxIOM4NJcGCRNQABlEIJgAB4YOEQQIBHRJkDYF0wAA5A5oE5nSpqAAGCwAJEx9ocIHlItUJATxOxUQYIMQ0rBsOjev0wKNqHl0VjDtUcMIaPSYB0QECAHRpECVHAEgCCSCqMFJ5KOVJphFJnGZrNposkoiAA).

Or another option is to assert `funName` type based on your `functionHelper` type, in which way you don't have to define a `Helper` type and make your `functionHelper` key arbitrary:

```
let funName = `add_${names[i]}` as keyof typeof functionHelper;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgEwQfXAUxgXhgCjALhjAFcBbAIzQCcBKLAPhgG8AoGGKtKYqsImANQwAjAG4WAX3EtQkWIhRQA7iCy4CRMpVoNmbDlx58+QgEzipLGeGjwkyKAAtOGbHkIkK1Opkat2nNy8-EIAzBbSAPSRMFAAngAOGAASaAA2SVRqrNHseQDaANZocYTQVACWYADmALqE7ppeOr5N2uK5ltZyMABmxGDAUBXgqRnU2foKqGBoADRT9sogC+zTTi4LXSwAbnBZYHCkaBBlUJU1+bVq+QDk6LdzMLfLj88baGi3tdK9IFk4NJcGAVNQABlEIJgAB4YOEQQIBHR-DAgbB+mAAHJHVwwAAG0wAJExDscIPkKrUJHj4BAYMU4iBerFEmgmX0BkMRmAxplxOw0QYIMQ0rBsBiuaN0pl8hjscdajhhDR+TBZBAQECAHRpEDVHB4gCCSCq1RgxNJJwpVMIxM4wtF1JVklEQA)

Comment: Why would you write an interface that is weakly typed allowing reading and writing arbitrary properties when the resulting inference would be strongly typed? `const functionHelper = {add_one, add_two, add_three}` and `type Helper = typeof functionHelper`

Comment: Can you provide your suggestion ? The key `funName` is dynamically generated. How can you make the strong typing work here ? @AluanHaddad

Comment: I don't think that would work ? He needs the `Helper` type first before `functionHelper` is defined. @AluanHaddad

Comment: I see. Not till 4.1. Then you can strongly type computed keys